# Cannot Export a Data Extension to External SFTP Delivery Location in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to export a data extension (within Contact Builder/Email Studio) to an external SFTP site.  The external SFTP site has been set up in File Locations for a long time.  The only option I am seeing for the ‘Delivery Location’ is the Enhanced FTP.  I have always been able to download a Data Extension to any of the File Locations that have been created in Email Studio…Admin…File Locations.

Does anyone know why this changed?

Comment: I never exported in this way are we sure it changed?

Comment: Yes - I have used it many times before and it always contained the full list from the File Locations.

Comment: Supposedly this didn't work effective and they removed these options, EFTP and S3 buckets are the only option now